# Is this a bug in org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl?

Tags: java, hibernate

What concrete ancestor class in the *[org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/SessionImpl.html)* inheritance hierarchy, overrides *[Object.equals(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))* in such a way that the test at line "/* *3* */" below returns false?

---

```
package deduper;

import org.hibernate.*;

public class SessionEqualsPuzzler { 

    public static void main( String... fubar ){

        Session aSession  /* = ... Get a valid session instance from SessionFactory... */; /* 1 */

        assert ( aSession == aSession ) : "This error message WILL NEVER be shown..."; /* 2 */

        boolean isEqual = aSession.equals( aSession ); /* 3 */

        assert ( isEqual  ) : "This error message SHOULD never be shown — but it is anyway for some unknown reason...: " + isEqual; /* 4 */

    }

}
```

---

If you run the above with the "*-ea*" — *enable assertions* — switch, there will be an *[AssertionError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html)* thrown at the line labeled "/* *4* */".

I've searched everywhere I could think of. But as far as I was able to find out, *[SessionImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/SessionImpl.html)* does not appear to — *nor does any of its ancestors* — override *[Object.equals(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))*.

What's puzzling is, line "/* *2* */" evaluates to true but line "/* *3* */" does not!

To my understanding, that "*shallow*" identity check ("==") is exactly what the default *[Object.equals(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))* does. Right?

I am working under the assumption that *[SessionImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/SessionImpl.html)* does not override the default *[Object.equals(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))* anywhere up its inheritance hierarchy.

Does anybody else know why the *[SessionImpl.equals(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))* call above evaluates to false?

---

*Incidentally, I'm using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final, for what it's worth.*

---

***UPDATE***: [*Hibernate have acknowledged the existence of the bug, resolved it super quickly*](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11067) — thanks again @SteveEbersole — [*and the fix is scheduled to be released in version 5.2.3*](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11067).

Comment: What is printed when you execute `System.out.println(aSession.getClass())`?

Comment: "To my understanding, that "shallow" identity check ("==") is exactly what the default Object.equals(Object) does. Right?".  No - except for primitives, the "==" operator will only validate that the object is the exact same object.  If you want .equals then you need to call .equals.

Comment: @JBNizet - `System.out.println(aSession.getClass())` prints `class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14`

Incidentally, I'm using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final, for what it's worth.

Comment: OK. So it's not an instance of SessionImpl. It's a dynamic proxy, and the invocation handler of this proxy decides how to implement equals(). And it, apparently, decided to always return false.

Comment: @JBNizet - OK. Now I know :¬) Learn something new everyday. Thanks.

Is there some way to make HIbernate **not** use proxies?

Comment: A very big part of Hibernate is based on proxies (lazy-loading, etc.). So no. Also, I was probably wrong: the handler doesn't always return false. It just delegates to the real session, and the real session thus compares itself to the proxy, which returns false.

Comment: @JBNizet - Ah! Got it. Thanks again. 

If you'd like credit for an answer,  "_please, do the needful_" — as my off-shore colleagues would put it :¬)

Comment: >  No - except for primitives, the "==" operator will only validate that the 
>  object is the exact same object. If you want .equals then you need to 
>  call .equals.
_____________
I had a comeback for you, @stdunbar. But then I thought, "*Why bother? He's already embarrased himself just fine on his own.*"

Comment: @deduper Any particular reason why you did not put a breakpoint in the `equals` method and debug it? Then you would yourself find the answer to the question immediately.

Comment: In general, some expected behaviors are so elementary, @DraganBozanovic, that when I see an unexpected behavior I "_just know_" the thing is broken.

Say I'm driving in my car and the engine starts making loud metallic grinding noises, bellows out thick black smoke, cuts off, then silently rolls to a dead stop. 

I don't know anything about the inner workings of car engines (_cont_)...

Comment: ...But I **_do_** know — _at the level of a layman driver_ — what the expected behavior of a correctly-functioning car should be. I don't need to pop the hood. I already know from the noises, the smoke and the absence of forward motion, that I need to put her in the shop.

In Java, @DraganBozanovic, the mere fact that something as elementary as `x.equals(x)` returning `false` tells me that **_something_**  is broken **_somewhere_**. And that's all I need to know as the "_driver of the car_". Id est: I don't need to step through a debugger (_cont_)...

Comment: ...For something as elementary as `x.equals(x)` returning `false`, @DraganBozanovic, it's the "_mechanic's_" job to know what's broken where, and how to fix it.

Comment: @deduper It makes sense what you are telling, thanks for the clarification. But you are a _mechanic_ here.  _Drivers_ are users of your application. I was just pointing out the rules of Stack Overflow, which require question askers to post their effort to make things easier for others to find out a solution, and to make it easier for you to get a more accurate answer. You would agree that debugging a non-working piece of code is one of the first steps to isolate the cause of the issue.

Comment: You've made incorrect assumptions, \@DraganBozanovic, in every comment you've posted to this thread. The details of which are neither here nor there. So that's all I'll say about them.

But I will say this. I could not have hoped for "_more acurrate answers_" than the two killer replies I got from @JBNizet and \@Douglas. 

The fact, \@DraganBozanovic, that it took only two replies to result in Hibernate fixing the bug super quickly after I first asked the question here, is proof enough to me that (_cont_)...

Comment: ...I did indeed "_make things easier_" for at least two clever SO commenters — plus Hibernate themselves — "_to isolate the cause of the issue_".  

The fact that \@SteveEbersole acknowledged that I have indeed exposed a bug, is definitive proof that [_the information I provided_](https://github.com/deduper/hibernate.5.2.2.session.equals.bug/tree/HHH.11067.test.case) made it easy for him to find and quickly implement a fix.

Once again, Kind Thanks to @SteveEbersole.

Comment: That's all fine, no problem at all. :) I am sure that the negative score on your question is a dissatisfaction of other users with the amount of effort you made to find a solution, that's why I just wanted to point it out. For example, you would spare JB Nizet's time to ask you the first question if you debugged it out yourself.

Comment: Also @deduper as for this being "my job, not yours"...  wow.  Too many things wrong there in your view-point to even begin to get into.  Way to embrace the spirit of Open Source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is known and reported, tracked at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7528. As @JBNizet mentioned in the comments, it's part of Hibernate's use of dynamic proxies.

The bug is currently only marked as affecting a version prior to 5.x, which is no longer maintained. If you can verify that it is still present in Hibernate 5.x, please report that on the bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks @Douglas. 

Something told me this had to be an actual bug. Thanks for backing me up :¬)

Again, I'm using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final, for what it's worth.

Comment: Because \@Douglas confirmed my assumption that I was seeing an actual bug — _actually answering the question in my title_ — I will go ahead and accept \@Douglas' answer. But I am nevertheless just as grateful to @JBNizet for filling me in on Hibernate's use of proxies.

Comment: This bug is related to entity proxies, not `Session` proxies, which are two unrelated things. After all, @deduper do you use IBM JVM? The bug which Douglas mentions is only reproducible there...

Comment: [_Session.equals(Object) Implemented With Confusing Non-Idiomatic Behavior_](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11067)

Comment: FWIW HHH-7528 relates to Hibernate's proxying of JDBC objects (much like a DataSource or JCA would do), not the proxying of entities.  Just to clear up some confusion.

Comment: NP, I just like to be sure the historical record is accurate in regards to these issues and pointers to them, as much as I can.  It helps uses in the long run.  Thanks to you for helping others :)

Answer (score 1):

So, technically... no.  No, it is not "a bug in org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl".  However there was a bug in how thread-based current session handling handled the question of 2 sessions being equal.  I fixed that; see the discussion on the [HHH-11067](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11067) issue you opened.